# Excel VBA Replace Text with Two Arrays

Tags: arrays, string, excel, vba, replace

I would like to replace the values in column A:A using arrays:

```
Dim aValueNew() As String
Dim aValueOld() As String

aValueNew = Split("ABC,DEF,GHI", ",")
aValueOld = Split("123,456,789", ",")
```

123 needs to be replaced by ABC, 456 by DEF and so forth.

What is the most efficient way of doing this? I am struggling on how to include the Replace function in a loop and your help would be appreciated. Something like:

```
For i = 0 to i = 2
Range("A:A").Replace What:= aValueOld(i), Replacement:=aValueNew(i), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. You may find the [documentation for For...Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601%28v=office.14%29.aspx) helpful.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 2
    Range("A:A").Replace What:=aValueOld(i), Replacement:=aValueNew(i), _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Jean-François! Next was the missing part :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
For i = 0 to UBound(aValueOld)
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Replace What:= aValueOld(i), Replacement:=aValueNew(i), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

**Note:**
Your `For` statement was wrong
If count of values are the bound of array use `UBound(<Array Name>)`

Comment: Thanks! I guess it is safer to use UBound, just in case value are added/removed in the array.